# trigger another plugin only when data loaded from another url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ticker, news-ticker

I want to get some data from an external page than display it with a ticker effect.

There is an example on its own website but there the data is not pulled from another page (http://www.jquerynewsticker.com).

With the following code, data is successfully loaded from the external page.

But ticker plugin does not work while I dont get any errors.

```
    $(function FeedTicker() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckins",
            success: function(data) {
            $(".feedme").html(data);
            $('#js-news').ajaxSuccess(function(){
               $(this).ticker();
            })
            },
            error: function(data) {
            $(".feedme").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#js-news').ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $(this).ticker();
})
```

Comment: I tried it both with and without .when().done() and in and out of the FeedTicker function but it didnt work.

Comment: oh, have you tried to call the function within ajax method after             `$(".feedme").html(data);` that's weird, are you sure ticker plugin has been loaded successfully?